# jQuery working on Firefox but partially on IE8

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

I have made a jQuery script who working well on Firefox but not on IE8.
On IE, when I select an option, the title don't change but in Firefox it do it.
I'm using jQuery v 1.11.3, suposed to be compatible with IE8.
My HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mise à jour des lits</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Mise à jour des lits</h1>

    <form method="post" action="#">
        <label>Veuillez entre le code de l'Unité Fonctionelle:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="uf" /><br><br>

        <select name="uf" id="uf-resultat">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
        </select>

        <div class="hidden">
            <h2>Modification de l'UF : <span id="titre"></span></h2>
            <i>Dernière mise à jour: </i>

            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Mettre à jour">
            <button id="fermer">Fermer</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="../Vue/JS/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../Vue/JS/ajax-uf.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my jQuery script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var uf = $('#uf');

// Lorsque le cadre commence à saisir le numéro de son UF
uf.keyup(function(){
    if (uf.val().length >= 2){
        var valeur = 'uf=' + uf.val();

        // On lance la requête AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url  : 'ajax.php',
            data : valeur,
            success : function(server_response){
                $('#uf-resultat').append(server_response);

                // Si le cadre rajoute un chiffre à son UF où s'il l'efface, on efface les options du select
                // Pour éviter que la nouvelle requête AJAX se rajoute à celle effectuée précédemment
                uf.keyup(function(){
                    $('#uf-resultat option').remove();
                    $('#uf-resultat').append('<option selected="selected"></option>');
                });

                // Lorsque le cadre à selectionné son UF
                $('#uf-resultat option').click(function(){
                    var uf_choisi = $('#uf-resultat option:selected').val();

                    // On efface le titre au cas où il y aurait un Uf qui aurait déjà été sélectionné
                    $('#titre').contents().filter(function(){
                        return this.nodeType == 3;
                    }).remove();

                    $('#titre').append(uf_choisi);

                    // On déclanche une nouvelle requête AJAX pour savoir la date de la dernière modification
                    // Ainsi que la personne qui a modifié le compte de clits pour cet UF
                    console.log(uf_choisi);
                }); 
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Anyone have an idea please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error u got in console.

Comment: I have nothing on my IE console.

Comment: use breakpoints or console.log() after at every scipt..

Comment: As you can see in my original code, i have already a console.log() but nothing appear on my console ....

Comment: After some breakpoint, I have found that IE never enter in the function $('#uf-resultat option').click(function(). What's wrong with that ?

Comment: why dont u use `onchange ` instead of on `click function` https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally,

This solution is working :

```
$('select').change(function(){
```

Thanks for help